# WPF - Expander in Grid - eating space

Tags: c#, wpf, expander

I have very simple xaml.

```
<Grid Margin="0,50,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <!--<RowDefinition Height="50"/>-->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Expander Header=""
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          ExpandDirection="Right"
          IsExpanded="True"
          Grid.Column="0" 
          Grid.Row="0"
          Height="Auto"
           >
<!-- My List control -->
</Expander>
<TabControl Name="ExecutionTab" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<!-- soem tabs here -->
</TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Now after collasping expander the left part [row=0,col=0] being shown as empty with space.
What we want is right part [row=0,col=1] should take whole space.

What should be done in this case ?
I have tried HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" to Tab control but not working.

Do I need to add event handler like on collapse and change width of grid.. but it does not seems to good way ?

Can anyone suggest better way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a Grid is not the best way to achieve what you want. You should use a DockPanel instead with LastChildFill = "true". I can't try it now but I would imagine it like this:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
 <Expander Header=""
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          ExpandDirection="Right"
          IsExpanded="True"
          DockPanel.Dock="Left"
          Height="Auto"
           >
<!-- My List control -->
</Expander>
<TabControl Name="ExecutionTab" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
<!-- soem tabs here -->
</TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

This should make the tab control always take the entire remaining space.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Tried this one but after this changes only Expander is getting displayed and when it is collapsed only Tabcontrol is displayed. So at a time only expander or tabcontrol is displayed.

Comment: I just tried locally and it worked. Anyway we can see the entire page code?

Comment: Yes.. It worked for me. Problem was interally xaml was using Grid again. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

You can make this work by setting your column definitions to:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The complete code to show this working is below:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Expander ExpandDirection="Right" IsExpanded="True">
     <TextBlock FontSize="50">Text For Expander</TextBlock>
    </Expander>
    <TabControl Name="ExecutionTab" Grid.Column="1">
        <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
            <TextBox FontSize="50" TextWrapping="Wrap">Text for Tab 1</TextBox>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
            <TextBox FontSize="50" TextWrapping="Wrap">Text for Tab 1</TextBox>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

If you add the xaml above to a window, you should see the following

[image: Window with Expander expanded!]

[image: Window with Expander collapsed]

Comment: Tried above with columndefination auto but after that only Expander is getting displayed and when it is collapsed only Tabcontrol is displayed.

Comment: If you put the above code in a window of reasonable size, you will initially see the expander text and the tabs. The tabs will be narrow. When the expander is collapsed, the expander text will disappear and the tab will occupy the whole window (apart from the expander button). Did you try the xaml exactly as above?

Comment: What issue did you see?  It works as I expected but maybe you're trying to do something different.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make you `ColumnDefinition.Width` to `Auto` and if you want fixed width for your `TabControl` you should give `Width` to `TabControl`.

```
<Grid Margin="0,50,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Tried this one but after this changes only Expander is getting displayed and when it is collapsed only Tabcontrol is displayed. So at a time only expander or tabcontrol is displayed.